# didSelectRowAtIndexPath returns out of bounds index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Whenever I have enough items loaded into my UITableView that I can scroll down far enough to move items off of the screen the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method code I have implemented spits out an invalid index value which crashes my app.

Here is my method code, pretty standard fair:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView.visibleCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selImg = cell.imageView.image;

    [self next];    
}
```

As an example, if the tableView has 15 rows from data entered into the data source only 12 will show at any one time on the screen.  According to the tableView those elements at 0-11.  If I scroll down to the other three rows and select one the tableView is still showing that it has elements 0-11 but the indexPath says that row 14 was selected.

This throws the following NSRangeException:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index
>   14 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]'

Searched on Google and SO a bit and could not find an issue similar to mine and I don't really know how to correct this issue as this code, or something similar, seems to be the standard way to get the index value of a selected row.

Comment: can you show ur cell for row at indexpath method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView.visibleCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thanks.  Is there a reason why the other method would not work or does it have to do with how UITableViews cache the 'hidden' cell rows?

Comment: `visibleCells` return only list of visible on screen and it not equal of all count of cells in your tableView, indexPath.row will be equal a position of your invisible cell. If this right you can marked my answer. Thanks

Comment: Will do, waiting for the answer lockout time to expire.